# Refresh Page Every time PWA is opened - PWA

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA where users can redeem stuff. The problem comes when it's PWA on iOS because they don't communicate, so users are able to redeem twice (once in the browser and once on the PWA; if they're sneaky), because PWA doesn't update on what's happening on the browser.

My solution for this would be that every time people are using PWA on iOS and they open the app, it will reload to be updated with the same information the browser one is.

first, I created a function to detect if the user is on iOs and a function detecting if the user is on standalone, to know they're on PWA, so combining these who I created:

```
if(is_iOS() && isInStandaloneMode()){
   window.location.reload(true)
}
```

But this only created a reload on loop, so I wasn't able to even see the information once.

Is there a way to be able to refresh the page every time the PWA is opened?

Comment: Why are you redeeming in clientside and not on the server? By doing it on the server would prevent double as you can check if already redeemed.

Comment: Im doing it on the server, the problem is that if people redeem something on the web and they refresh everything is good, but if they have PWA installed and they go to the PWA the thing is gonna be there "unredeemed" because PWA and safari don't communicate on iOS

Comment: Add code serverside which checks if it's already been redeemed and respond with a message (or reload the page), rather then letting it though. If you want it updated on start/open your need to add code to check a state, socket.io would suit, as it would go though connect etc which then you can provide a state back without needing to specifically look for *just opened app again*.

Comment: you can use local storage you should set some flag in storage after you refresh the page and check if that flag is in the local storage before you do refresh